# M1 Mac Ruby on Rails msgpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, msgpack, apple-m1

After attempting to use Ruby on Rails on an M1 Mac, I came across the following error. It seems `msgpack` is getting a loading error related to the M1 Mac's architecture. Has anyone found a work around for this?

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `require': dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle, 0x0009): missing compatible arch in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.3.3/lib/msgpack.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:44:in `rescue in with_gems'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:40:in `with_gems'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `require_relative'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap.rb:5:in `require_relative'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:2:in `require_relative'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/marcupio/Desktop/Projects/stocktalk/back/stocktalk_app_api/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
    from /Users/marcupio/Desktop/Projects/stocktalk/back/stocktalk_app_api/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/marcupio/Desktop/Projects/stocktalk/back/stocktalk_app_api/config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'
    from /Users/marcupio/Desktop/Projects/stocktalk/back/stocktalk_app_api/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:157:in `serve'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:145:in `block in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `loop'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Did you build its C extension on the system in question?